# Sending multiple data with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Simple question here. I want to send two strings as data in an ajax request. Problem is in this ajax request it only sends the second sting of data and not the first. How would I send both of those in one ajax request?

```
$.ajax({ url: '#{add_cards_path}', 
  type: 'POST',
  beforeSend: function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', '#{form_authenticity_token}')},
  dataType: "json",

  data: 'credit_uri=' + response.data.uri,  
  data: 'address=' + $('.address').val(),
  success: function(response) {
    window.location.assign(location.protocol + '//' + location.host);
    }
});
```

I want to send "credit_uri" and "address". How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with data you can send multiple data to the server.

```
data: {credit_uri: response.data.uri, address: $('.address').val() }
```

Its like an object.

Comment: Your always Welcome :)

Answer (score 5):

Objects cannot contain duplicate keys, which in your case is `data`.

Use an object literal:

```
data: {credit_uri: response.data.uri, address: $('.address').val() }
```

`$.ajax` will convert the data to a query string.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
$.ajax({ url: '#{add_cards_path}', 
      type: 'POST',
      beforeSend: function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', '#    {form_authenticity_token}')},
      dataType: "json",
      data: {"credit_uri:" + response.data.uri + ", "address:" + $('.address').val()} 
      success: function(response) {
        window.location.assign(location.protocol + '//' + location.host);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code :-

```
$.ajax({ url: '#{add_cards_path}', 
      type: 'POST',
      beforeSend: function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', '#{form_authenticity_token}')},
      dataType: "json",

      data: 'credit_uri=' + response.data.uri+'&address='+$('.address').val(),
      success: function(response) {
        window.location.assign(location.protocol + '//' + location.host);
        }
    });
```